# Pass function with args to props in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm getting a very strange error running this code (React+Typescript):

```
// doesn't work
<TestClass
    input={InputFunction}
/>
```

and also this code:

```
// doesen't work
<TestClass
    input={(props:TestProps) => InputFunction}
/>
```

These will both return the error "No overload matches this call." The strange thing is, the below will work, thanks to the `defaultProps` supplied in `TestClass` (where `InputFunction` is supplied).

```
// works!
<TestClass/>
```

My source code is below. You can replicate it by creating two files (`InputFunction.ts` and `TestClass.tsx`) using the below code, and then attempting to run the above code in a separate file in the same project (alongside import statements and the usual boilerplate).

```
// InputFunction.ts
export const InputFunction = <T>(
    props: { widthRatio: number },
): number => {
    return 0
};
```

```
// TestClass.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import { InputFunction } from "./InputFunction"


export interface TestProps {
    readonly input?: ((props: TestProps) => number);
}

export class TestClass extends React.Component<TestProps> {
    public static defaultProps = {
        input: InputFunction,
    };

    public render() {
        return (
            null
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Post code of the `inputFunction`

Comment: It seems that you want something like this:
```
<SomeClass inputArg={inputFunction} />
```

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov I tried that but I got a similar error (it also says ```No overload matches this call```)

Comment: I think the reason behind this error is the `inputFunction` accepting `{ widthRatio: number}` as a `props` parameter, while `SomeClass` excepts a function accepting `CandlestickSeriesProps` which contains many more parameters besides `widthRatio`.

Comment: @MaksBabarowski Hmmm, then why does it work when I pass `inputFunction` as part of `SomeClass`'s `defaultProps`?

Comment: @MaksBabarowski I've totally changed my question so as to make it more simple. You can replicate it on your machine now, probably.

Comment: is that a circular dependency in your code - in defining the "TestProps" interface, you use the TestProps interface itself ?

Comment: No, because the third code example works. @BaoHuynhLam

Answer (score 1):

In your interface TestProps you declare `input?` with a question mark. This makes it optional and explains why your example without any props works.

I think the main error comes from your definition of the props interface:

```
export interface TestProps {
    readonly input?: ((props: TestProps) => number);
}
```

This is recursive. You don't want a parameter of type `TestProps`. Instead, the parameter should match the signature of your function `props: { widthRatio: number }`

Once the signature matches I would expect the compiler to accept `InputFunction`.